# Run TCL script in regular intervals with continuous results

Tags: while-loop, tcl, infinite-loop

I have encountered a problem in one of my TCL scripts. I need to run it in an infinite loop with a terminating condition and in every loop I need to write some output. This is the basic code that im using:

```
proc wr {i} {
    puts -nonewline "$i"
}

proc do {roof} {
    set end 0
    while {$end < $roof} {
        after 1000
        wr $end
        incr end
    }
}

do 10
```

The expected behaviour is that every second there will be a new output until $end == $roof. But instead after running this script, the console window is busy for 10 seconds and after that time, the entire output prints out at once.

Thank you for your advice :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you don't flush `stdout`.

If you modify your script so it flushes `stdout`:

```
proc wr {i} {
    puts -nonewline "$i"
    flush stdout
}

proc do {roof} {
    set end 0
    while {$end < $roof} {
        after 1000
        wr $end
        incr end
    }
}

do 10
```

It will work. You can also change the buffering of the `stdout` channel to none, the default is `line`:

```
fconfigure stdout -buffering none
```

If you write more than one line, the default buffering will flush stdout when it encounters a newline, but you never write a newline.

Comment: It works great in a TCL script, thank you! But when I try the same in TK - changing label text in intervals - flushing the stdout won't obviously work, but there must be a different workaround, could you help mne with that? :)

Comment: @Tomáš'GunsBlazing'Frček Hmm, I'm not sure if this will fix your issue, but I use recursion instead of looping to animate `gif` pictures. I have my proc to change the image label, and I use `after $ms procname` at the end of the `proc`.

Comment: use either `update` or schedule the next execution with `after 1000 [list wr $end]`

Comment: The recursion is working well, thank you both, guys :)

Comment: By default, `stdout` is `line` buffered when going to a terminal, and `full` buffered when going to a pipe or file. (`stderr` is always unbuffered by default since it is used for writing out things like crash dumps, if that's necessary. You shouldn't write non-diagnostic info on `stderr`.) All settings are overridable with `fconfigure`.